# Showing java.lang.NullPointerException at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:150) in Testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

It is showing me error while I am using CSVReader

```
public class firstclass {
    private static WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    @DataProvider(name="readcredentials")
    public Object[][] readcredentials() throws Exception{

        CSVReader readunamepass= new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:/My Projects  New/BSP/Aut/Credentials.csv"));
        List<String[]> list = readunamepass.readAll();  
        Iterator<String[]> readnext = list.iterator();

        while(readnext.hasNext())
        {

            String[] credential = readnext.next();
            System.out.println("" +readnext);
            System.out.println("username"+credential[0]+"password" +credential[1]);
            f(credential[0], credential[1]);

         }
        return null;
    }

    @Test(priority=1, dataProvider="readcredentials")
    public void f(String credential, String credential2) throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("http://192.168.1.111/lms");
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("txtUserId")).sendKeys( credential);
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("txtPwd")).sendKeys(credential2);
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("btnSign")).click();
        //Thread.sleep(100000);
        //System.out.println("This is method");
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver(){

        return driver;

    }
```

In this program, @dataprovider is reading uname and password from a csv file and passing it to Test method.
I am not able to provide return type so that I have provided null.Please help
More detail -
I have tried to return object but it is showing me some suggestions. I have tried but showing error in compilation. See image [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H64Ys.png)

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K00KY.png)

Comment: Please post complete stacktrace.

Comment: Here is stacktrace Andrew -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got the correct answer by amitbhoraniya and it worked for me.Thank you Amit.
Also updated on http://www.knowledgeworldforyou.com/?p=351
https://knowledgeworldforyou.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/unable-to-get-value-from-csvread-in-testng-here-is-solution-of-showing-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-testng-internal-methodinvocationhelper-invokedataprovidermethodinvocationhelper-java150/

```
    public class firstclass {
    private static WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    @DataProvider(name="readcredentials")
    public Object[][] readcredentials() throws Exception{

        CSVReader readunamepass= new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:/My Projects New/DSP/Aut/Credentials.csv"));
        List<String[]> list = readunamepass.readAll();
        String[][] array = new String[list.size()][];
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            array[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Test(priority=0, dataProvider="readcredentials")
    public void f1(String value, String value1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(value+" "+value1);
        getDriver().get("http://192.168.1.128/lms");
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("txtUserId")).sendKeys(value);
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("txtPwd")).sendKeys(value1);
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("btnSign")).click();

        //to do
        //your logic
    }



  public WebDriver getDriver(){

  return driver;


 }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data provider returns null, so you are getting null pointer exception,

> It should return `Object[][]`

Also you dont need don't call `f(credential[0], credential[1])` method in readcredentials() method, instead of that your readcredentials() method shoud return `Object[][]`, In your case it could be String[][]
For more details how to use data provider with parameters you can refer testng official documentation: [Parameters with DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

```
public class firstclass {


    @DataProvider(name="readcredentials")
    public Object[][] readcredentials() throws Exception{

        CSVReader readunamepass= new CSVReader(new FileReader("hello.csv"));
        List<String[]> list = readunamepass.readAll();
        String[][] array = new String[list.size()][];
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            array[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Test(priority=1, dataProvider="readcredentials")
    public void f(String value, String value1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(value+" "+value1);
        //to do
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Added more details in post for your solution- I have tried what you have said Amit but it is showing me message like in image -I have tried to return object but it is showing me some suggestions. I have tried but showing error in compilation. See image [Error image][1]

Comment: I have updated the answer and implemented the code and its working.  Can you please try this.

Comment: Thank you Amit for your effort. :). You thought out of the box :)

Comment: Hi @dinesh if answer has solved your question please accept the answer by clicking on tickmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: Ohk, sorry I was unaware of this as I am new to this stackoverflow site. Now it's done. Thanks :)